# .exe jar file reads txt file but the contents are all broken in different computer (shows alien language..)

Tags: java, text, fonts

I recently made a game(Korean conversation) and trying to distribute to my friends.

I exported .exe Jar file in Eclipse and zipped it along with all txt files that are a part of the game. and I send it to my friends. But they all said it reads file, but the text are all broken; it shows an alien language..
**It worked good in my computer, not a problem at all,** but it seems it doesn't work in other computer. So I tried changing "encoding" to see if that might make any difference.

1. ANSI
2. Unicode
3. Unicode Bigendian
4. UTF-8

All of the txt files that I sent were "ANSI" : it can be read in Jar file, but output is an alien language.
so I tried the rest (Unicode, UTF-8, Unicode Bigendian), but then it cannot even be read, making FileNotFound Error.

How could I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Take control over the encoding of the .txt files by setting their encoding explicitly in the file's properties in eclipse, say to UTF-8.

Then in the code, take control over the process of reading those files by either :

- reading only byte arrays from them and converting them to Strings while explicitly specifying the UTF-8 encoding
- reading only through I/O Streams/Readers that have been made aware of the UTF-8 encoding by passing the UTF-8 charset as an argument in their construction.